(Potential) Ambiguity in text fragment
I have a question regarding the quote below: does или here connect «палками» or «засечь палками» to «каким-нибудь иным способом», or is it even unclear? In other words: is the talking about another method of execution or is it about an other mean for засечь? According to my understanding of the word способ I tend to the former.

Самое удобное для правительства было бы казнить отказавшегося: засечь палками или каким-нибудь иным способом, как это делалось прежде. (Л. Н. Толстой, «Царство Божие внутри вас, или христианство не как мистическое учение, а как новое жизнепонимание», 1893 г.)

Note: I am interested in whether to a native language speaker there is any ambiguity in this very text fragment.


Note: I am interested in whether to a native language speaker there is any ambiguity in this very text fragment.

From the purely grammatical perspective, there is an ambiguity in which verb exactly каким-нибудь иным способом complements: засечь or казнить.
That said, засечь палками или иным способом would be a syllepsis: both палками and иным способом are in the same case and do both complement the same verb, but their agreements convey different meanings. This construct would sound as funny as, say, the English phrase "he lost his temper and his glasses", or Russian за окном шёл снег и рота красноармейцев.
That said, even if we accept that засечь иным способом is the intended meaning, it would be a very strange thing to say. There were exactly two ways of corporal punishment to which the word засечь could be applied: flogging and "running the gauntlet". Both of them were not considered capital punishment, but, in practice, starting from a certain number of lashes, did mean certain death. So saying "any other way" instead of "flogging" would be a redundant generalization.
That said, Leo Tolstoy's writing is widely known for not being aligned with conventional rules of rhetorics and text composition, deliberately or not. Even though a thing like that, as any unintentional pun in a serious text, or an unneeded generalization, would normally be considered poor writing style, it would not be at all out of place in his works.

There isn't any ambiguity here. The word способ can be directly translated as approach. So, it means a different type of execution. If the author wanted to express the idea of using a different thing to perform the same type of execution, he could have used the word орудие or the word инструмент. The resulting sentence would look like this:

Самое удобное для правительства было бы казнить отказавшегося: засечь
палками или каким-нибудь иным орудием (инструментом), как это делалось прежде.

